# Extending HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I want to add functionality to HttpsURLConnection so I tried to extend  this class like so:

```
public abstract class HTTPClient extends HttpsURLConnection
```

When I'm trying to use this class:

```
HTTPClient con = (HTTPClient) url.openConnection();
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to HTTPClient
```

What is the problem here and how it can be fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you paste the part where you define the ``url`` variable?

Comment: Why do you believe that `url.openConnection()` knows anything about your subclass of `HttpsURLConnection`?  It returns an implementation of `URLConnection` that is on a different branch of the inheritance hierarchy and is in no way related to your subclass.  For this to work `URL` would have to be customizable with a factory to create connections, and that is not part of the API.

Comment: HttpURLConnection belongs to the same hierarchy as URLConnection - to imply that the user should have known that the system would throw an implementation to it is absurd

Answer (score 0):

You can extend as follows:

```
class H extends HttpURLConnection {
  URLConnection uc;
  public H(URL url) {
    super(url);
    try { uc=url.openConnection(); } catch(Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace();  }
 }

 public boolean usingProxy() { return true; }

 public void disconnect() { }

 public void connect() { }

}
```